# Neighborhood of list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
 lst={{0., 0.}, {0.1, 0.0998334}, {0.2, 0.198669}, {0.3, 0.29552}, {0.4, 
  0.389418}, {0.5, 0.479426}, {0.6, 0.564642}, {0.7, 0.644218}, {0.8, 
   0.717356}, {0.9, 0.783327}, {1., 0.841471}, {1.1, 0.891207}, {1.2, 
  0.932039}, {1.3, 0.963558}, {1.4, 0.98545}, {1.5, 0.997495}, {1.6, 
  0.999574}, {1.7, 0.991665}, {1.8, 0.973848}, {1.9, 0.9463}, {2., 
  0.909297}, {2.1, 0.863209}, {2.2, 0.808496}, {2.3, 0.745705}, {2.4, 
   0.675463}, {2.5, 0.598472}, {2.6, 0.515501}, {2.7, 0.42738}, {2.8, 
  0.334988}, {2.9, 0.239249}, {3., 0.14112}, {3.1, 
  0.0415807}, {3.2, -0.0583741}, {3.3, -0.157746}, {3.4, -0.255541}, \
  {3.5, -0.350783}, {3.6, -0.44252}, {3.7, -0.529836}, {3.8, \
  -0.611858}, {3.9, -0.687766}, {4., -0.756802}, {4.1, -0.818277}, \
  {4.2, -0.871576}, {4.3, -0.916166}, {4.4, -0.951602}, {4.5, \
  -0.97753}, {4.6, -0.993691}, {4.7, -0.999923}, {4.8, -0.996165}, \
  {4.9, -0.982453}, {5., -0.958924}, {5.1, -0.925815}, {5.2, \
 -0.883455}, {5.3, -0.832267}, {5.4, -0.772764}, {5.5, -0.70554}, \
  {5.6, -0.631267}, {5.7, -0.550686}, {5.8, -0.464602}, {5.9, \
  -0.373877}, {6., -0.279415}, {6.1, -0.182163}, {6.2, -0.0830894}, \
  {6.3, 0.0168139}, {6.4, 0.116549}, {6.5, 0.21512}, {6.6, 
    0.311541}, {6.7, 0.40485}, {6.8, 0.494113}, {6.9, 0.57844}, {7., 
     0.656987}, {7.1, 0.728969}, {7.2, 0.793668}, {7.3, 0.850437}, {7.4, 
    0.898708}, {7.5, 0.938}, {7.6, 0.96792}, {7.7, 0.988168}, {7.8, 
   0.998543}, {7.9, 0.998941}, {8., 0.989358}, {8.1, 0.96989}, {8.2, 
    0.940731}, {8.3, 0.902172}, {8.4, 0.854599}, {8.5, 0.798487}, {8.6, 
   0.734397}, {8.7, 0.662969}, {8.8, 0.584917}, {8.9, 0.501021}, {9., 
    0.412118}, {9.1, 0.319098}, {9.2, 0.22289}, {9.3, 0.124454}, {9.4, 
     0.0247754}, {9.5, -0.0751511}, {9.6, -0.174327}, {9.7, -0.271761}, \
    {9.8, -0.366479}, {9.9, -0.457536}, {10., -0.544021}, {1, 0.5}, {3, 
     0.5}};
```

If I plot this list using `ListPlot`, I would see that there are two outlier points. I know there are some posts here to detect those points. However, what I am looking for is an efficient command that tests if a point is surrounded by neighboring points; if no points exist in its proximity, then the code should consider that point as an outlier. This is a small code that I want to use for very long and 3D list.

Thanks for help.

Comment: `Nearest`? `ClusteringComponents`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know the neighborhood radius, you could use the following approach:

```
outlier[data_, d_] := Pick[
    data,
    Length /@ Nearest[data, data, {Infinity, d}],
    1
]
```

For you example data set, the neighborhood radius is about `.2`, so:

```
outliers = outlier[lst, .2]
```

> {{1, 0.5}, {3, 0.5}}

Here is a plot:

```
ListPlot[lst /. Thread[outliers -> Thread@Style[outliers, Red]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Greatly appreciated. Just  a quick question. What if I have 3D points. Will this apply?

Comment: @qahtah It should work with any dimension.

Comment: Thanks Carl for your help.